# syntax --primordial-accounts-file <FILENAME>

Tags: local-cluster

I am trying to start my own development cluster and would like to stake additional nodes during genesis. I need to use the flag `--primordial-accounts-file <FILENAME>` but need to know the proper syntax to separate the identity account and balance of the accounts I need to add.

Is there a more in-depth help file description besides `solana-genesis --primordial-accounts-file <FILENAME> --help`? `The location of pubkey for primordial accounts and balance`

I can get my bootstrap validator to start voting and slots are confirming but I can't get the bootstrap validator to process transactions (like `transfer` or `airdrop`) the signature is shown but never finalized.

I am hoping that is I can get my second remote node staked in genesis it will allow the cluster to process transactions.

Comment: Thanks @Jon C,  do you know what the `executable` and `data` fields are for?

Comment: I had gotten this far from trial and error:
`val_accounts: 
        owner: "<stake acct pubkey>" 
        balance: 500000000 
        withdrawer: "<withdraw auth pubkey>"` 

But it was throwing an error wanting `data`

Can you help me decipher that a bit more? Withdrawer must be wrong...and what would `executable` mean in this context?

Comment: @jon-c would you know why a local cluster would process slots but not finalize transactions? I can see the slots moving and have a remote node syncing the chain as well. I can initiate `airdrop` or `transfer` but it shows me the signature and never finalizes the tx...

Comment: Please comment on my answer next time, since I don't get notifications here! "Executable" is whether the account is a program, and "data" is the data in the account, in base-64. If it's a stake account, you'll need to encode the stake account information as base-64. You can get some example account data by running `solana account --output json <ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>`

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunately undocumented, but looking at the code, you need to create a `Hashmap<Pubkey, Base64Account>`, where account data is a base-64 encoded string, and then dump it to yaml, ie:

```
        let mut genesis_accounts = HashMap::new();
        genesis_accounts.insert(
            solana_sdk::pubkey::new_rand().to_string(),
            Base64Account {
                owner: solana_sdk::pubkey::new_rand().to_string(),
                balance: 2,
                executable: false,
                data: String::from("aGVsbG8="),
            },
        );
        genesis_accounts.insert(
            solana_sdk::pubkey::new_rand().to_string(),
            Base64Account {
                owner: solana_sdk::pubkey::new_rand().to_string(),
                balance: 1,
                executable: true,
                data: String::from("aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="),
            },
        );
        genesis_accounts.insert(
            solana_sdk::pubkey::new_rand().to_string(),
            Base64Account {
                owner: solana_sdk::pubkey::new_rand().to_string(),
                balance: 3,
                executable: true,
                data: String::from("bWUgaGVsbG8gdG8gd29ybGQ="),
            },
        );

        let serialized = serde_yaml::to_string(&genesis_accounts).unwrap();
        let path = Path::new("test_append_primordial_accounts_to_genesis.yml");
        let mut file = File::create(path).unwrap();
        file.write_all(b"---\n").unwrap();
        file.write_all(&serialized.into_bytes()).unwrap();
```

This was lovingly copied from one of the `solana-genesis` tests https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/cc6c4540766d595a3720e39346b4500f2e2d982c/genesis/src/main.rs#L713