# How to add funded accounts during solana-genesis for local cluster

Tags: local-cluster

What is the process to add 10 or so accounts during solana-genesis with a pre-determined amount of lamports for use with a local cluster? I am not using test-validator or multi-node demo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntax --primordial-accounts-file <FILENAME>](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/syntax-primordial-accounts-file-filename)